# How to display the splash screen when the app start

Tags: java, android

How to display a splash screen when the app starts, I try to add a splash screen to the app but it is not working for me.
Here is my code

**SplashActivity**

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int SPLASH_TIME = 3000; //This is 3 seconds
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splach);

    //Code to start timer and take action after the timer ends
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Do any action here. Now we are moving to next page
            Intent mySuperIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(mySuperIntent);

            //This 'finish()' is for exiting the app when back button pressed from Home page which is ActivityHome
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME);
}
}
```

**Manifest**

```
    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Post your manifest file which should indicate main launcher activity - most likely not set to splash activity.

Comment: @Andy I add it.

Comment: Yes - your app is set to invoke the MainActivity initially - which is not what you need - change it to SplashActivity (which then invokes MainActivity) - I'd look at the git repo (but its down right now).  Basically swap these in your manifest.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your splash must be the launcher activity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should put this part in the tag of start activity.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

For example :

```
<activity android:name=".StartActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Hope it will help you a little.